# Change UITabBar selected view programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I'm trying to update my `UITabBar` selected view programmatically I've tried below code :

```
UIViewController *currentView = self.frostedViewController.contentViewController;
NSLog(@"Current Index %lu", currentView.tabBarController.selectedIndex);
currentView.tabBarController.selectedIndex = 3;
NSLog(@"changing index %lu", currentView.tabBarController.selectedIndex);

//self.frostedViewController.contentViewController = categorie;
[self.frostedViewController hideMenuViewController];
```

But the tab bar view is not changing check this image : 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

By setting the selectedViewController:

```
func selectTab(atIndex index: Int) {
    if index >= 0 && index < tabBarController.viewControllers.count {
       tabBarController.selectedViewController = tabBarController.viewControllers[index]
    }
}
```